# laravel 5.6 datatable pagination not working

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, pagination, laravel-5.6

I'm using laravel 5.6 and try to add pagination to bootstrap datatable. But it's not working.I got error.Please help me to find mistake I did.

**Error**

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

**designation.blade.php(View)**

```
 @if(count($designations)>=1)
    <table class="table table-dark" id="designationTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Designation Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Create At</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($designations as $designation)
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{$designation->id}}</th>
            <td>{{$designation->designation_type}}</td>
            <td>{{$designation->status}}</td>
            <td>{{$designation->created_at}}</td>
            <td>
              <button type="" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn_update_designation">Update</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{ $designations->links() }}
  @endif
```

**DesignationController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Designation;

class DesignationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $designations = Designation::all();
       return view('pages.designation')->with('designations',$designations);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add controller file code.

Comment: @rika Add `paginate()` method in controller instaed of `all()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the paginate() method in your controller file.

```
public function index()
{
    $designations = Designation::paginate(10);
    return view('pages.designation')->with('designations',$designations); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Paginating Eloquent Results**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)

> You may also paginate Eloquent queries. In this example, we will
>   paginate the User model with 15 items per page. As you can see, the
>   syntax is nearly identical to paginating query builder results:

```
$designations = Designation::paginate(15);
```

> You may call paginate after setting other constraints on the query,
>   such as where clauses:

```
$designations = Designation::where('column', 'value')->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the paginate() method in your controller file.

```
public function index()
{
    $designations = Designation::paginate(15);
    return view('pages.designation')->compact('designations',$designations); 
}
```